Корректная адаптация имени Тонио-лунатик (Tonho da Lua) на русский
В бразильском телесериале 1993 года "Секрет тропиканки" ("Женщина из песка") есть чокнутый персонаж Tonho da Lua. (пер. da Lua — "с луны").
Есть несколько вариантов переложения имени на русский:

Тонио Лунатик
Тонио-лунатик
Тоньо Лунатик
Тоньо-лунатик
Тони Лунатик

Склоняюсь к "Тонио-лунатик":

"Тонио" лучше звучит для русского уха, чем "Тоньо";
"-лунатик" по аналогии с "Джек-потрошитель".


Устоявшегося написания нет. Наиболее оптимальным представляется вариант через дефис.
По правилам приложение пишется через дефис в случае слияния определяемого существительного и приложения в одно сложное интонационно-смысловое целое:
Иван-царевич, Иванушка-дурачок, Аника-воин, Дюма-отец, Рокфеллер-старший (но: Катон Старший — прозвище исторического лица.
Что касается самого имени, в фильме, насколько помнится, его звали Тонио, а не Тоньо.
